# Pourquoi n'y a-t-il pas d'étude dans les technologies ?

Tags: étymologie, grec

J'ai toujours cru que les mots finissant en *-logie* étaient la science d'une chose (par exemple la biologie, de βίος *vie* et λόγος *discours*, *traité*, est la science de la vie).

Je me demande donc pourquoi la technologie échappe à cette règle, alors qu'elle désigne les techniques de pointe (« Toutes ces technologies nous rendent idiots »)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le suffixe [-logie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-logie) est très productif, il ne se limite pas à la science d'une chose. Par exemple, une *tétralogie* n'est pas une science du nombre 4.

En fait, le mot *technologie* a été construit plusieurs fois, dans des sens différents. Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/technologie) donne des exemples signifiants. En 1809, Lamarck utilise ce mot pour désigner l'ensemble des termes techniques d'un domaine (on dirait aujourd'hui *terminologie*) :

> On doit distinguer la nomenclature de cette autre partie de l'art que l'on nomme technologie.

Cela dit, le mot [τεχνολογία](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%AF%CE%B1) existait déjà en grec, où il désignait une λογία au sujet d'une τέχνη, c'est-à-dire ce que l'on appellerait un livre technique. En français, le mot apparaît au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle pour désigner l'étude des techniques — la « théorie de l'industrie pratique », disait Ampère. Au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, le mot a évolué pour désigner ce que contient une τεχνολογία et qu'étudie la théorie de l'industrie pratique, c'est-à-dire l'ensemble des techniques d'un domaine (« la technologie du papier »).

Dans son sens courant, le mot *technologie* désigne l'ensemble des techniques, surtout celles récentes dont on parle le plus parce qu'elles sont inhabituelles et surprennent.

Pour conclure, je propose de rattacher ce sens à l'étymologie (sans aucun fondement historique bien sûr, c'est une étymologie populaire) : la technologie, c'est la manière dont les techniques s'expriment.

Answer (score 3):

Je ne pense pas que ce soit une exception, la technologie est la science des techniques.

> **Technologie**, subst. fém.
>   […]
>   B. − Science des techniques, étude systématique des procédés, des méthodes, des instruments ou des outils propres à un ou plusieurs domaine(s) technique(s), art(s) ou métier(s).
>   (**[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/technologie)**)

Comment: Mais précisément, quand je dis que _les nouvelles technologies ont eu beaucoup de succès à Noël_, je ne me réfère pas à cette science. Je me réfère à cette science quand je dis qu'il y a un IUT près de chez moi.

Comment: @rds: Dans ce cas c'est un autre sens, c'est un ensemble de techniques.  Voir sur le lien indiqué le paragraphe C.

Comment: J'ai eu des de technologie en école d'ingénieur, et il s'agissait bien du sens B dans les définitions du CNTRL. Le professeur râlait d'ailleurs souvent sur le glissement vers le sens C, qu'il qualifait d'anglicisme à éviter.

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que dans ta phrase, « technologie » est utilisé pour indiquer le produit de la technologie, plutôt que la technologie même. C'est une métonymie